# Using pagefactory can initialize webelement with visible element, if FindBy matches multiple webelement on the page

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a page which has multiple button 'OK' for different sections. However, at any given point of time only one 'OK' button is visible and can be identified using advanced xpath mechanisms (But not always)

```
//button[@value='OK' and not(@style='')]
```

My Question here is that, can i extend the class PageFactory and override the initialize function by enhancing it by adding a mechanism which processes all the webelements returned by `@FindBy` decoraters. I will check which one is visible using `.isDiplayed()` and assign the visible one? This way, i need not have multiple lines of code across pages.

Currently more elements are matched for xpath `//button[@value='OK']` and hence i am getting `NoSuchElementException`. Ideally there should be `AmbiguousElementException`, but we dont have any such...

Any help or pointers here please?

Comment: If you're talking about `PageFactory.InitElements` that won't actually search for the elements, it just initializes the fields. The webelement is found when it is used instead. So if your xpath correctly identifies the only visible one, it should work just fine, but it just might not be displayed yet when you're calling it.

Comment: Read the notes on PageFactory again. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory Specifically: "...every time we call a method on the WebElement, the driver will go and find it on the current page again." If you construct your XPath correctly, your WebElement could be a different button every time!

Comment: I completely understand all your suggestion. I think i didnt phrase my question clearly. For my given xpath, there are multiple elements matching, but only one 1 visible at any point of time.

Using PageFactory (Xpath returns 2 WebElement, 1st is not visible and 2nd is visible): driver throws timeout exception due to internal wait. Also i cannot enhance my xpath, because all properties are same.